# Debug Java generic Comparator

Tags: java, generics

```
class MyComparator<K,V> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> {

    public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {

                V v1 = me1.getValue();
                V v2 = me2.getValue();

                if(v1.size() > v2.size())
                    return 1;
                else if(v1.size() < v2.size())
                    return -1;
                else
                     return 0;
    }
}
```

Help needed.

Error:

```
    javacode$ javac -Xdiags:verbose Anagrams1.java
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: > expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                   ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: '(' expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                         ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: > expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: < expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                 ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: illegal start of expression
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                  ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                     ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: '(' expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                          ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: illegal start of type
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                                 ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: ';' expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                                     ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: ';' expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                                                               ^
    Anagrams1.java:6: error: ';' expected
        public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {
                                                                                                    ^
    11 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2)
```

to

```
public int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2)
```

You shouldn't specify the type parameters in both the class declaration and method declaration.

And the method itself should be :

```
public int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {

    List<V> v1 = me1.getValue(); // changed here
    List<V> v2 = me2.getValue(); // changed here

    if(v1.size() > v2.size())
        return 1;
    else if(v1.size() < v2.size())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

since you are comparing two `Map.Entry<K,List<V>>` instances, not `Map.Entry<K,V>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the type witness in the method signature:

```
public int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public <Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> int compare
```

to

```
public int compare
```